# What does "you'll end up needing a much bigger toothbrush" mean?

Tags: dialogue, shameless

I'm rewatching the series premiere of *Shameless* (U.S.) and one line has always perplexed me.

Lip is talking to Steve after the latter gives him some medical 'advice' about a 'skeletal fact' and Lip replies,

> Talk out of your ass with that much conviction and you'll end up
>   needing a much bigger toothbrush; that's a[n] anal fact.

What on Earth does this quip mean?

Comment: Which part of the line are you referring to?

Comment: Needing a much bigger toothbrush,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that Steve would have to insert the toothbrush through his anus instead of inserting it into his mouth, so he'd need a really long handle. Not a really good metaphor to my way of thinking.